# Display repeating itself every time i hit submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So i modified a wordpress plugin to suit my needs. 
Now everything basically works as i wanted to, but i still have a little problem and i don't know how to resolve it.

My goal was to still be able to access and modify the data selected on my quiz even after hitting the submit button.
To do so i modified the code so that the results part would not replace the data selection but come after it. (Hitting the back on the brower would not work).

Now every time i hit submit, i have another result added. If i hit submit 4 times, i have 4 results one after the other (actually it's the latest result repeating itself).
I would like it to display only the latest. Hope i could explain it correctly.

Anyone has an idea?

```js
function qmnFormSubmit( quiz_form_id ) {
 var quiz_id = +jQuery( '#' + quiz_form_id ).find( '.qmn_quiz_id' ).val();
 var $container = jQuery( '#' + quiz_form_id ).closest( '.qmn_quiz_container' );
 var result = qmnValidation( '#' + quiz_form_id + ' *', quiz_form_id );

 if ( ! result ) { return result; }

 jQuery( '.mlw_qmn_quiz input:radio' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
 jQuery( '.mlw_qmn_quiz input:checkbox' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
 jQuery( '.mlw_qmn_quiz select' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
 jQuery( '.mlw_qmn_question_comment' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
 jQuery( '.mlw_answer_open_text' ).attr( 'disabled', false );

 var data = {
  action: 'qmn_process_quiz',
  quizData: jQuery( '#' + quiz_form_id ).serialize()
 };

 qsmEndTimeTakenTimer();

 if ( qmn_quiz_data[quiz_id].hasOwnProperty( 'timer_limit' ) ) {
  qmnEndTimer( quiz_id );
 }

// jQuery( '#' + quiz_form_id + ' input[type=submit]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
 qsmDisplayLoading( $container );
// containerBuffer= $container;
 jQuery.post( qmn_ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
  qmnDisplayResults( JSON.parse( response ), quiz_form_id, $container );
 });

 return false;
}

function qsmDisplayLoading( $container ) {
// $container.empty();
 $container.append( '<div id="loader_div" class="qsm-spinner-loader"></div>' );
 qsmScrollTo( $container );
}

function qmnDisplayResults( results, quiz_form_id, $container ) {
// $container.empty();
 jQuery('#loader_div').remove();
// $container=containerBuffer;
 if ( results.redirect ) {
  window.open( results.redirect_url, '_blank' );
 } else {
  $container.append( '<div class="qmn_results_page"></div>' );
  $container.find( '.qmn_results_page' ).html( results.display );
  qsmScrollTo( $container );
 }
}
```

Comment: SInce you're doing the post yourself through ajax, what about using preventDefault so the page doesn't reload? That way you can keep the results inside a variable.

Comment: @Shilly : Not sure that i completely got what you meant, but wouldn't that actually prevent the data to be submitted a 2nd time? I need to be able to.
If not, where should I use preventDefault() ?

Comment: Clicking the 'submit' button of a form will automatically post the form to the form target and reload the page. But since you use $.post() to submit the form, you can prevent the default behaviour of the submit button so you don't reload and when you don't reload, you can just keep the results inside a variable and do whatever with it.

Comment: @shilly : thanks for the tip!